# 2D to 1D numpy array with indices of column for each row

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to index a column for each row in a matrix.

Suppose I have a numpy array `A` with the shape `(n,m)`.
I also have a numpy array `B` with the shape `(n,)` containing integers between 0 and m, so they can be used as indices for the 2nd axis of `A`.

I want to get a numpy array `C` with shape `(n,)` with `C[i] = A[i,B[i]]`, so every row of `A` yields one value based on the index in `B`.

Surely I could use this last expression in a for loop or list comprehension, but how would I do it using the efficiency of numpy?

My first intuition was `C = A[:,B]` but this clearly yields something else. (shape `(n,n)`)

Comment: I can't think of any straightforward way to do this with list comprehension, but if you wanted to clean up the syntax you could do something like `C = np.array([A[i, val] for i, val in enumerate(B)])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, try:

```py
C = A[range(len(B)), B]
```

This should yield `C[i] = A[i,B[i]]`

Comment: This works! I now use `C = A[np.arange(B.size),B]`, because I think it will be slightly more efficient with `np.arange` instead of `range`